# value out of range double in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to add a double in mysql database table,
I have set the the double to DOUBLE(5,2) and the value I'm trying to add is 157.82 but I get this error message :

> Data truncation: Out of range value for column 'vægt_kg' at row 1

I have already tried all other data types and multiple inputs and i have tried DOUBLE(5;2) which I read would help but it wouldn't accept the ;. I have also tried with DOUBLE(50,2) and it still said out of range.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `patient`.`patientInfo` (
  `cpr` INT(10) NOT NULL,
  `forNavn` VARCHAR(21) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `efterNavn` VARCHAR(25) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `højde_cm` INT(3) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `vægt_kg` DOUBLE(5,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `beskrivelse` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `adresse` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `telefon` INT(8) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cpr`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4
COLLATE = utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

query:

```
INSERT INTO patientInfo (cpr, forNavn, efterNavn, højde_cm, vægt_kg, beskrivelse, adresse, telefon) 
VALUES ('1234567890','mille','san','175','157.82','hej','vejgade 23', '34343434');
```

Comment: DOUBLE(5,2) should work, please post the queries you perform.  Also remember the 5 means your total units of precision 5. Which means only 3 units before the decimal place.

Comment: Are you trying to addd 5.2?

Comment: Can you show us a `CREATE TABLE` statement, so we get the type of **each** fields. Your error might come from elsewhere than your `DOUBLE(5,2)` field

Comment: @Cid I have added the CREATE TABLE statement

Comment: The query you've shown doesn't reproduce the error you describe. Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0c00ba342c892c417353f9555f8f39c6 . Whatever is causing your problem, it isn't the code above. P.S. What version of mySQL are you using?

Comment: I have now changed to a float and it now works not sure what the problem was, I am new in using the mysql workbench so perhaps i've made a mistake while using it

Comment: What is the **exact** error message ? I can't reproduce it

Comment: @cid Data truncation: Out of range value for column 'vægt_kg' at row 1

Comment: Are you getting this error when you are directly trying to execute this query in phpMyAdmin or MySQL Workbench ?

Comment: as stated ADyson, what version of MySQL are you using ?